# Getting Error for skin customization to Catalust2-H-Trans after upgrading from DNN 9.1 to DNN 9.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I get the error below after upgrading to DNN 9.2  from DNN 9.1.  I have gone to look at the code from the specific file for that error.  The error wipes away the site CSS for the customization.

```
    Could Not Load Theme: /Portals/_default/Skins/Catalyst2-H-Trans/Template-SemiBoxed-02.ascx, Error: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DotNetNuke\Portals\_default\Skins\Catalyst2-H-Trans\Template-SemiBoxed-02.ascx(20): error BC30456: 'Version' is not a member of 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings'

    <%@ Control language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGO" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Logo.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="CURRENTDATE" Src="~/Admin/Skins/CurrentDate.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LANGUAGE" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Language.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="SEARCH" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Search.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="BREADCRUMB" Src="~/Admin/Skins/BreadCrumb.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGIN" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Login.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="USER" Src="~/Admin/Skins/User.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="COPYRIGHT" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Copyright.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TERMS" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Terms.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="PRIVACY" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Privacy.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="NAV" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Nav.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins" Assembly="DotNetNuke" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="JavaScriptLibraryInclude" Src="~/admin/Skins/JavaScriptLibraryInclude.ascx" %>
<dnn:JavaScriptLibraryInclude runat="server" Name="jQuery-Migrate" Version="1.2.1" SpecificVersion="LatestMajor" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%= SkinPath %>drnuke-main.js'></script>
<% 
    Dim strScriptsToAdd As String = ""
    Try        
        Dim arrVersion() As String = PortalSettings.Version.Split(".")
        If (CInt(arrVersion(0)) <= 4) Or ((CInt(arrVersion(0)) = 5) And (CInt(arrVersion(1)) = 0)) Then
            strScriptsToAdd = strScriptsToAdd & "<script type='text/javascript' src='" & SkinPath & "drnuke-menu.js'></script>"
        End If
        If (CInt(arrVersion(0)) <= 4) Then
            strScriptsToAdd = strScriptsToAdd & "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='" & SkinPath & "css/dnn4.css'>"
        End If
    Catch
        strScriptsToAdd = strScriptsToAdd & "<script type='text/javascript' src='" & SkinPath & "drnuke-menu.js'></script>"
    End Try
%>
<%=strScriptsToAdd%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit that file, simply change it to:

```
<% 
    Dim strScriptsToAdd As String = ""
    strScriptsToAdd = strScriptsToAdd & "<script type='text/javascript' src='" & SkinPath & "drnuke-menu.js'></script>"
%>
```

You aren't running DNN 4 or 5, no need to maintain support for those legacy versions.